# Docker stucks while pulling "scrapinghub/splash"

Tags: docker, pull, scrapy-splash

[View the problem image in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY2BX.png)

You can view the problem image in this above link.
I have tried using "Docker desktop" but it only showed "connecting to Docker hub"
so I thought of trying it through "docker toolbox" but still it caused this problem.

I am pretty sure its not internet issue but its stuck like it is in the picture.
It does not complete "docker pull scrapinghub/splash" command

Can anybody help with this issue?

Comment: Hi anjan, you should share what you've done and give some details about your problem. Then you may ask for help. These kinds of questions are not suitable.

Comment: sir,I have provided my issues within the picture in the link.I hope now its more clear